# Updating points one by one to a window using Zelle graphics.py

Tags: python-3.x, graphics2d, zelle-graphics

I have written some codes to draw randomly located points, as many as I wanted to, and make them spread like fluid for a while. Also I wanted them not to get into each other. There is no problem running it, but in some cases it takes really long time to finish a point's spreading, so I realized that's not that efficient.

I would be happy to get some help to make it more efficient.

[This is what I meant by "like fluid"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPEil.gif)

```
from graphics import *
import time, random

racepoints = {} # {0:[(),()],1:[(),()]}
allpoints = []
races = {}
tx, ty = int(input("x=")), int(input("y="))

def Window():
    global win, sure, spreadSize
    win = GraphWin("Pencere", tx, ty)
    starttime = time.time()
    Start()
    spreadSize = int(input("Başlangıç boyutu?"))
    Spread(spreadSize)
    finishtime = time.time()
    sure = (finishtime - starttime)
    writeTime()
    print("Bitti! Ve {} saniye sürdü!".format(sure))
    time.sleep(5)


def writeTime():
    timefile = open("C:\\Python36\\timefile.py", "r")
    gotta_rewrite = timefile.readlines()
    timefile.close()
    timefile = open("C:\\Python36\\timefile.py", "w")
    gotta_rewrite.append("\n{} ırk, {} genişlik, {}*{} alan, {} saniye sürdü.".format(racecount, spreadSize, tx, ty, sure))
    timefile.seek(0)
    timefile.writelines(gotta_rewrite)
    timefile.close()


def Start():
    global racecount
    racecount = int(input("Kaç tane ırk olsun?"))
    for i in range(racecount):
        randomcolor = color_rgb(random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
        races[i] = randomcolor
        racepoints[i] = []
        nx = random.randrange(tx)
        ny = random.randrange(ty)
        randomstartpoint = Point(nx, ny)
        randomstartpoint.setFill(races[i])
        randomstartpoint.draw(win)
        allpoints.append((nx, ny))
        (racepoints[i]).append((nx, ny))


def Spread(maxsize):
    defaultsize = maxsize
    for i in range(racecount):
        maxsize = defaultsize
        while maxsize > 0:
            for point in list(racepoints[i]):
                lx, ly = point
                ax, ay = 0, 0
                while ax == 0 and ay == 0:
                    ax = random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
                    ay = random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
                if (lx + ax, ly + ay) not in allpoints:
                    lx += ax
                    ly += ay
                    newpoint = Point(lx, ly)
                    newpoint.setFill(races[i])
                    newpoint.draw(win)
                    (racepoints[i]).append((lx, ly))
                    allpoints.append((lx, ly))
                else:
                    pass
            maxsize -= 1


Window()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a different approach this time compared to my initial attempt in that this solution relies heavily on set logic to maintain the points.  (The colors come off as a bit pastel due to my use of `win.plot()` instead of `Point.draw()` but that's a minor implementation detail)

As before, I use the color as a dictionary key so my code makes sure the random color chosen is unique.

```
import time
from random import randrange
from collections import defaultdict
from graphics import *

def Window():
    global tx, ty, win

    tx, ty = int(input("x = ")), int(input("y = "))
    race_count = int(input("How many races do you have? "))
    spread_size = int(input("Maximum spread? "))

    win = GraphWin("Window", tx, ty)

    start_time = time.time()

    Start(race_count)
    Spread(spread_size)

    finish_time = time.time()
    time_difference = finish_time - start_time

    print("Done! And it took {} seconds!".format(time_difference))
    writeTime(time_difference, spread_size, race_count)
    time.sleep(5)

def writeTime(sure, spread_size, race_count):
    try:
        with open("timefile.py") as time_file:
            gotta_rewrite = time_file.readlines()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        gotta_rewrite = []

    gotta_rewrite.append("\n{} race, {} width, {} * {} space, {} seconds.".format(race_count, spread_size, tx, ty, sure))

    with open("timefile.py", "w") as time_file:
        time_file.writelines(gotta_rewrite)

def Start(race_count):
    for _ in range(race_count):
        random_color = color_rgb(randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255))

        while random_color in races:
            random_color = color_rgb(randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255))

        nx, ny = randrange(tx), randrange(ty)
        win.plot(nx, ny, random_color)

        races[random_color].add((nx, ny))

def Spread(spread_size):
    for _ in range(spread_size):
        for color, points in races.items():
            for point in list(points):  # need copy of points as it'll be modified in loop

                candidates = set()

                x, y = point

                for dy in range(-1, 2):
                    for dx in range(-1, 2):
                        candidates.add((x + dx, y + dy))

                candidates = candidates.difference(*races.values())

                if candidates:
                    new_point = candidates.pop()
                    points.add(new_point)

                    nx, ny = new_point

                    if 0 < nx < tx and 0 < ny < ty:  # only draw visible points
                        win.plot(nx, ny, color)

races = defaultdict(set)

Window()
```

Working the points round robin, rather than completing one and moving onto another, seems truer to the intent.  You can compare your *new* solution on the left to mine on the right where they both have 50 races:

[image]

On mine on the right, you can nearly count all 50 races but on yours, you can only spot half that number due to losses from overlap.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code a little bit so now if the total of drawn pixels are greater than blank pixels it'll check the new pixel's coordinates on blank pixels. Because of blank pixels (that ready to be colored) are getting lesser and lesser it becomes easier and faster to check if new pixel is able to be drawn. 200 races, 25 spreadSize, x=200, y=200 was complete in 512.4622814655304 seconds before changing it, now it's 384.0333812236786 seconds. 
New version:

```
from graphics import *
import time, random, io

date = "{}.{}.{}".format(time.strftime("%d"),time.strftime("%m"),time.strftime("%Y"))
racepoints = {} # {0:[(),()],1:[(),()]}
allpoints = []
space = []
races = {}
tx, ty = int(input("x=")), int(input("y="))

for i in range(tx+1):
    for a in range(ty+1):
        space.append((i, a))

def Window():
    global win, sure, spreadSize
    win = GraphWin("Pencere", tx, ty)
    Start()
    spreadSize = int(input("Başlangıç boyutu?"))
    starttime = time.time()
    Spread(spreadSize)
    finishtime = time.time()
    sure = (finishtime - starttime)
    writeTime()
    print("Bitti! Ve {} saniye sürdü!".format(sure))
    time.sleep(5)


def writeTime():
    with io.open("C:\\Python36\\timefile.py", "r", encoding="utf-8") as timefile:
        gotta_rewrite = timefile.readlines()
        timefile.close()
    gotta_rewrite.append("\n{} ırk, {} genişlik, {}*{} alan, {} saniye sürdü. {}".format(racecount, spreadSize, tx, ty, sure, date))
    with io.open("C:\\Python36\\timefile.py", "w", encoding="utf-8") as timefile:
        timefile.seek(0)
        timefile.writelines(gotta_rewrite)
        timefile.close()


def Start():
    global racecount
    racecount = int(input("Kaç tane ırk olsun?"))
    for i in range(racecount):
        randomcolor = color_rgb(random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
        races[i] = randomcolor
        racepoints[i] = []
        nx, ny = 0, 0
        while (nx, ny) == (0,0) or (nx,ny) in allpoints:
            nx = random.randrange(tx)
            ny = random.randrange(ty)
        randomstartpoint = Point(nx, ny)
        randomstartpoint.setFill(races[i])
        randomstartpoint.draw(win)
        allpoints.append((nx, ny))
        (racepoints[i]).append((nx, ny))
        space.remove((nx, ny))


def Spread(maxsize):
    defaultsize = maxsize
    for i in range(racecount):
        maxsize = defaultsize
        while maxsize > 0:
            for point in list(racepoints[i]):
                lx, ly = point
                ax, ay = 0, 0
                while ax == 0 and ay == 0:
                    ax = random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
                    ay = random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
                lx += ax
                ly += ay
                if len(space) > len(allpoints) and (lx, ly) not in allpoints and lx in range(tx) and ly in range(ty):
                    newpoint = Point(lx, ly)
                    newpoint.setFill(races[i])
                    newpoint.draw(win)
                    racepoints[i].append((lx, ly))
                    allpoints.append((lx, ly))
                    space.remove((lx, ly))
                elif len(allpoints) > len(space) and (lx, ly) in space and lx in range(tx) and ly in range(ty):
                    newpoint = Point(lx, ly)
                    newpoint.setFill(races[i])
                    newpoint.draw(win)
                    racepoints[i].append((lx, ly))
                    space.remove((lx, ly))
                else:
                    pass
            maxsize -= 1


Window()
```

Comment: You dismissed my earlier solution due to your requirement "I wanted them not to get into each other" but that's *exactly* what this solution is doing!  Look at it carefully.  Try x=100; y=100; races=6; spread=40 for a clearer view of this.